# Using Queue class to queue carriages of a Train - C++

Tags: c++, queue, linked-list, simulator

I am attempting make a simulator class that will use a Queue to add the Carriages from Train in to a Queue, so it will become a Queue of carriages. Carriage is also the dataType of the train class.

I will use a method to enqueue trains as they arrive, adding them to different queues. I will also have a method to dequeue trains once their cargo has been unloaded.

I have a Train class which has a private variable of:

```
LinkedList<Carriage> *list;
```

Queue class has a private variable of:

```
LinkedList<dataType> *list;
```

In my demo file I am calling:

```
Train* train1; //declare a train.

train1 = new Train(arr); //instantiate train with an array of integers

Queue<Carriage> queue1;  //declare a queue.

queue1 = new Queue<Carriage>(train1); //instantiate queue with train data.
```

I am having a problem with my queue class, I am not quite sure on how to implement it.

My Queue class.h:

```
template <typename dataType> //dataType
class Queue
{

public:
           Queue();

       Queue(dataType arr[]);

           ~Queue();

           void pop();

           void push(dataType data);

private:

    LinkedList<dataType> *list;

};

#include "Queue.template"
//there is also a namespace and a macroguard, left them out of this.
```

EDIT - Did not add enough information.

In the above demo file code, I want to be able to call queue1 = new Queue(train1);

When I do this I get errors so I know I'm doing something wrong with my constructor, as they are both linkedlists, do i need to use a loop to assign the carriages in to the queue?

What I need help with is getting the train carriages in to the queue.

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to make your question more specific. "I'm not sure how to implement is" isn't very specific. What have you tried? What sort of advice do you want?

Comment: Meta comment: Don't you think a Queue is the wrong abstraction for a train of carriages. Think about what are the operations that you can do on a Queue vs those you can do on a train carriage. E.g., how would you insert a carriage in the middle of the train ?

Comment: part of the simulation is using an unloading facility where the trains are processed and their loads removed, this is why the trains will be entering a queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing argument of type `LinkedList` to a constructor takes argument of array of `datatype`, which causes the error.

You can, however, loop through every `train1` element, and `push` it to the `Queue`.

As a note, `push` and `pop` are function names for the `stack`. `Queue` has `enqueue` and `dequeue`

Comment: I read somewhere that the new C++ library uses push and pop for both stacks and queues.

So are you saying I need to change the constructor to accept the train object, then in the constructor cycle through each position in the train pushing it in to the queue?